# Spawn ssh works in parent process, Using fork then try to spwan fail to return buffer to expect

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect, spawn

I am trying to Spawn a new SSH session with TCL but first i fork a 4 diffrent process each with unique ip as follow :

```tcl
foreach  vendor $vendorList {
        set pid [fork]

        switch $pid {
            -1  {
                puts "Fork attempt #$vendor failed."
            }
            0   {
                puts "I am child process vendor = $vendor ."
                $vendor ConnectSSH
                exec kill [pid]
            }
            default {
                lappend pids $pid
                puts "The parent just spawned child process #$vendor."
            }
        }
    }

    foreach id $pids {
        wait $id ;#need to add maximum time to wait
        puts "process id $id is done"
    }
    puts "all done"
```

While ConnectSSH is :

```tcl
#ConnectSSH

    puts "===== Function - Vendor:openConnection ====="

    set sid [spawn ssh "$user@$managementIP "]
    puts $sid
    set sid $spawn_id
    set logged_in 0
    set retry 0
    while {!$logged_in} {
        expect -i $sid timeout {
            if {$retry < 5} {
                puts "retry = $retry"
                after 5000
                incr retry
            } else {
                timedout "in while loop"
                return -1
            }
        } eof {
        # for some reason we lost connection to the application.
            timedout "spawn failed with eof"
            return -1
        } "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
            exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r"
        } "password" {
            exp_send -i $sid -- "$password\r"
            exp_send -i $sid -- "\r\r\r"
        } "$user" {
            set logged_in 1
            exp_send -i $sid -- "\r\r"
        } "No route to host" {
            puts "Failed to open ssh connection. No route to host. Exit."
            return -1
        } "timed out" {
            puts "Failed to open ssh connection. Connection timed out. Exit."
            return -1
        }

    }
```

I am getting new sid from Spawn but expect return "in while loop", seems like timeout.
When running not under "fork" all works great.